# Add button at the bottom of layout and scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have an activity layout that has 2 EditText and 3 Buttons. I want to apply a scrollview to the whole layout. The last button should always be at the bottom of the layout; it should also belong to the same scrollview as the other EditText and Buttons.

This is a visual description:

[image: The required output]

What I have done is not allowing the third button to be at the bottom of the layout. We also have to keep in mind that the screen sizes differ, so the positioning of the third button should be dynamic enough to be at the bottom of any screen size and belong to the scrollview as well.

My layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AddDetails" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:id="@+id/first_layout">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/firstNameEdit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="First Name"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="24sp" >
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/lastNameEdit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Last Name"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailEdit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Email address"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/locationEdit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Country"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/dateOfBirthEdit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Date of birth"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/first_layout">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/nextScreenBtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/next_button_selector"
                    android:text="Next"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest me a way to achieve the same.

Comment: keep `nextScreenBtn` code outside of scroll layout. so button will always be at bottom of screen.

Comment: @Prag'sシ can not do that, it should be inside the scrollview, that is the trickiest part of the whole story!

Comment: Not related to the answer, but you should not use RelativeLayout that often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try with this code..**

*just use this instead of your 'ScrollView' code..*

```java
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset" >       

 // continue your code

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518889/scroll-view-with-two-buttons-at-the-bottom-of-the-layout